# converting 'dd-mmm-yy' to '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' in bigquery ;

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to convert `STRING` datatype into `DATETIME` .
Converting `dd-mmm-yy` into `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S` in bigquery

eg : `Select PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', '01-JAN-2021') as parse;`

Comment: so do it! what the problem? give us more details ...

Answer (score 0):

**Converting to date/time data types**

If your data isn't in one of these data types, you can convert them by using **CAST** , one of the **PARSE** functions.

**Converting using CAST**

To convert your **STRING** to one of the **Date** data types, your **STRING Must** be in the following formats:

1. **DATE**: YYYY-MM-DD
2. **DATETIME**: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
3. **TIMESTAMP**: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS [timezone]
4. **TIME**: HH:MM:SS

`SELECT CAST('2017-06-04 14:44:00' AS DATETIME) AS datetime`

**datetime**

```
2017-06-04 14:44:00
```

**Converting from STRING to DATETIME datatype using Parse**

To use one of the **PARSE** functions, your **STRING** can be formatted any way you like, you'll just tell the function how it should read it. There is a **PARSE** function for each **Date/Time** Data type:

1. **DATE**: PARSE_DATE(format_string, date_string)
2. **DATETIME**: PARSE_DATETIME(format_string, datetime_string)
3. **TIMESTAMP**: PARSE_TIMESTAMP(format_string, timestamp_string[, timezone])
4. **TIME**: PARSE_TIME(format_string, time_string)

You can see the full list of **Format Strings** [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp)

For example, if your date was in this format: **07-Jan-2021 12:44:02**, You could use the following:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATETIME('%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S', '07-Jan-2021 12:44:02') AS parsed_datetime
```

**parsed_datetime**

```
2021-07-01 12:44:02
```

**Formatting your date/times**

To see the data in a more approachable format. We can make use of the **FORMAT** functions in BigQuery.

There is a **FORMAT** function for each **Date/Time** Datatype:

1. **DATE**: FORMAT_DATE(format_string, date)
2. **DATETIME**: FORMAT_DATETIME(format_string, datetime)
3. **TIMESTAMP**: FORMAT_TIMESTAMP(format_string, timestamp[, timezone])
4. **TIME**: FORMAT_TIME(format_string, time)

The **FORMAT** strings here are the same as for the **PARSE** function [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#supported_format_elements_for_timestamp)

So if you want to show your dates in a format of: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS then you could do `FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', datetime_column)`

⚠️ It's worth noting that **FORMAT** functions return **STRING** so if you wanted to use the result of **FORMAT** as a **DATE**, it won't work.